# PHP - using public function in one class but not in extended classes

Tags: php, class

I have 3 classes

```
class Header
{
    public function _after_save ()
    {
    }
}

class Line extends Header
{

}

class Details extends Line
{

}
```

Line extends header and Details extend line. 
Header has a function which ‘ll be called many pages in my site & I have made it public. I don’t want when Line and Details class to call the function _after_save() to execute but it’s getting executed as are extended classes.
I can’t make the function protected for obvious reasons.
Any help how I can achieve this

Comment: `I don't want when I call the function _after_save() to execute` So don't call it.

Comment: Show us the complete code. We will help you comment out the line which calls that function.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043268/php-restrict-calling-of-public-methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create branched structure.

```
class AbstractHeader
{

}

class Header extends AbstractHeader
{
    public function _after_save ()
    {
    }
}

class Line extends AbstractHeader
{

}

class Details extends AbstractHeader
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Looks a good choice but I have to unnecessarily create an extra class.. what I am looking for is a feature which allows a function to be public & can be executed from out side the class But  the child extended classesm wont inherit the function

Comment: @user2959149, you can override your function in child class and throw an excpetion there.

Comment: Thanks!!!Thats the last option just to define the function with out anything inside in all child extended classes but I was checking if there is any other elegant solution. Thanks again to you all for your valuable inputs!!!